# MySQL Select Column With X Words

Tags: mysql

I am trying to come up with a query that will select a row if a column has at least X words in it.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE IF COLUMN <has >= 3 words>
```

Coming up empty though.  Any ideas?

Comment: How do you define word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 words need at least 2 spaces. You can count the spaces in your column

```
select * from your_table
where length(your_column) - length(replace(your_column, ' ', '')) > 1
```

Comment: +1 Exactly! Oh my god, that was fast. Hardly could read the question when you've already answered it

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: No, `>1` means at least 2, which are 2 spaces for 3 words

Comment: Yupp, You are very right. I apologise for my wrong interpretation of your great logic.